# SQL Import from Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a spreadsheet that I am importing that contains some test data for my application that I am building. I am using SQL Server 2008 and I amd doing the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

When I try to import the data I get the following message(s):

**Messages**

1. Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while
   converting column "eventdate3" (78) to column "eventdate3" (219). 
   The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value
   could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.". (SQL
   Server Import and Export Wizard)
2. Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "output column
   "eventdate3" (219)" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred,
   and the error row disposition on "output column "eventdate3" (219)"
   specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified
   object of the specified component.  There may be error messages
   posted before this with more information about the failure.  (SQL
   Server Import and Export Wizard)
3. Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component
   "Data Conversion 0 - 0" (207) failed with error code 0xC0209029
   while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (208). The identified
   component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error
   is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause
   the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages
   posted before this with more information about the failure. (SQL
   Server Import and Export Wizard)

The eventdate3 column is currently of type datetime.  In the spread sheet the first two rows have a value of "NULL" and rows 3 and 4 have a Date value.

Is the "NULL" messing up the process?

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[teacherNotification](
    [finalId] [float] NULL,
    [schoolname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [studentnumber] [int] NULL,
    [studentid] [float] NULL,
    [studentSectionId] [float] NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [firstname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [classstartdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [coursename] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [TeacherId] [float] NULL,
    [TeacherSectionId] [float] NULL,
    [TeacherFN] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [TeacherLN] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventcode1] [float] NULL,
    [eventname1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate1] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventcode2] [float] NULL,
    [eventname2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate2] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventcode3] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventname3] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate3] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventcode4] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventname4] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate4] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventcode5] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventname5] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate5] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventcode6] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventname6] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate6] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventcode7] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventname7] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate7] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventcode8] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventname8] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate8] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventcode9] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventname9] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate9] [datetime] NULL,
    [eventcode10] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventname10] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [eventdate10] [datetime] NULL,
    [emailAddress] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: you don't give enough information... some source code... what library are you using for reading the excel file..

Comment: I am using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

Comment: sounds like the datatyoe in the table in SQL server and the data in the excel sheet do not match... can you show the definition of the table you are importing into ?

Comment: It can't be because of the NULL. I was able to load an excel sheet with NULL when the table accepted NULLs

Comment: @Jeff V, while you use the wizard to import the data, in the "Review Data Type Mapping", does it identifies the column type as Datetime?

Comment: everything seemed to match up...  I couldn't see anything that "stuck out".  I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a settings problem in the wizard. "Retain null values from the source as null values in the data flow" must be ticked, per this article:

http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2009/07/fix-for-ssis-error-conversion-returned.html

Comment: that is interesting.  He had the same error I did.  However, I was using an Excel spreadsheet and I don't see that checkbox available to me.  I wound up getting it work by changing the On Truncation flag to ignore.  Thanks for your help as this link helped getting me where i needed to get!